# Implementing custom callout button for "About"/ "Info"

Tags: ios, swift, calloutview

Im extremely new to iOS and i have a requirement where in table view, each cell displays list of stores near by and also an info button at the end which shows the timings of the stores. Info accessory button like this [image]and my requirement is to display callout alert as below on tap of that button.

[image]

Do I need to create custom view of small size and display that view every time when user taps on that? Please advice how to achieve this in Swift.

Comment: Yes, you need to create your own custom view.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy: Any suggestions how i can implement the lower triangle how it points to info button?

Comment: @Ashh You can achieve a view with bottom triangle at dynamic place with UIBezierPath. See Apple Docs for more info https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath